# Show that a statistic is ancillary

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, inference, order-statistics, ancillary-statistics

Let $X_{i} \sim U(0, \theta) $ and $X=(X_1,\dots,X_n)$. Show that 
$$ \frac{X_{(1)}}{X_{(n)}}$$

Is ancillary for theta

I coulxnt find a way of doing it that looks convenient. Any idea?

P.s: $X_{(i)} $  are the order statistics of the vector

Comment: Would it help you if you wrote it as $(X_{(1)}/\theta)/(X_{(n)}/\theta)$?

Comment: Expanding on my earlier hint, what's the distribution of $X_i/\theta$? Can you see the reason for my earlier hint?

Comment: No, I can't. Sorry

Comment: Then what's the distribution of $X_i/θ$? (This much should be obvious)

Comment: Uniform 0,1, right? I see that you writing the quocient as you did you are trying to show that it does not depends on theta, but I cant see how to say it formally

Comment: So, if, as we know, the mininum is one of the $X_i$ and so does the maximum, and I already know that the ratio between two uniforms (0,1) does not depends on theta, this is sufficient to conclude (formally) that the statistic is ancillary?

Answer (score 2):

Let $Y = \frac{X_{(1)}}{X_{(n)}} =\frac{X_{(1)}/\theta}{X_{(n)}/\theta}$. Note that
$$X_{(1)}/\theta = \min_i \{ X_i/\theta\}$$

where $X_i /\theta \sim U(0,1)$ and the vectors of $X_i/ \theta$ are formed by iid Uniform $(0,1)$ random variables (as we can easily prove). The same can be done to the maximum. In this case, we see that the distribution of $Y$ will not depend on theta.